# Is it possible to load one module only after the whole page has loaded?

Tags: php, module, joomla-3.4, module-display

On my site, one module is taking considerably longer to load than the other content on the page. I'm wondering if it's possible to delay the loading of this module? For example, after the page is loaded call a function to load the slow module part into its module position.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some more information about the module, like the name and what it does?

Comment: my module is custom image slider. in those having 4-5 image with title and description tag and it's come  full width on side. due to we need to upload 1200x650 resolution big image so it's look pretty. but due to that it's take long time to load on site.

Answer (score 1):

If the module is putting pressure on the database server, then it would be a good idea to address that. In any case, one way of doing this is to assign the module to a single menu item with an almost blank template (the template only has one position, which is the position of the module), and then load the page that the menu item points to in an iframe.

Comment: well can you have idea to load slider first image at time page load and rest image as per click on next/prev we load. in my case i have one slider module which have full width images and all images load at time page load due to it's take long time to load page.

Answer (score 1):

> my module is custom image slider. in those having 4-5 image with title and description tag and it's come full width on side. due to we need to upload 1200x650 resolution big image so it's look pretty. but due to that it's take long time to load on site.

1) change to a slider extension which supports "lazy image load" (unite revolution slider for example)

[More about lazy loading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667631/how-lazy-loading-images-using-javascript-works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667631/how-lazy-loading-images-using-javascript-works)

2) compress your images with 60-80% quality in JPG-format.

3) use caching / optimize your website ( https://www.jch-optimize.net/87-documentation/tutorials/100-how-to-prevent-the-plugin-cache-from-over-growing.html )